# Is this process predictable or not?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Consider a market model with two assets which are modeled as usual
by the stochastic process $S^0$ and $S^1$,  that is adapted to the filtration.

Can anyone tell if this process is predictable or not:

[image]

What I think is that it is not predictable as we know only $\xi_1$ and the other values of $\xi_t$ are given only when $S_{t-1}$ is greater than $S_{t-2}$, which contradicts predictability which says that we should be able to calculate the process when we are one period behind.

Comment: Please use latex next time, it makes you question much more understandable.

Comment: You write  "the other values of $\xi_t$ are given only when $S_{t−1}$ is greater than $S_{t−2}$". This is not true. The indicator function just means that $\xi_t$ is $1$ if $S_{t-1}$ is greater and $0$ else. This is well defined ...

Comment: It looks as though $\xi_t \in \mathscr{F}_{t-1}$. In this case it would be predictable.

Comment: I agree with @user25064 that the process is predictable since $\xi_t \in \mathcal{F}_{t-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't see $S^0$ appear anywhere, so I assume it is just used somewhere else.

Second, there is probably a point (i) in your question, because you included the point (ii).  I'd expect that $\xi_0$ is actually defined there.

If that's the case, then $\xi_t$ is predictable.

Otherwise, if $\xi_0$ is not defined anywhere then the process $\xi_t$ is simply not defined properly as there is no way to know $\xi_2$. I'd guess this is a mistake.

Comment: I agree, if the process is properly defined, then at time $t-1$ we know $S_{t-2}$ and $S_{t-1}$ and thus $\xi_t$ - and that's it.

Comment: @SRKX point i is another exercise so it is not related to the ii.And I think $S^0$ is given for discounting only.